# Set and get multiple information in bit format

Tags: c++, bit, bitmask

I have these bits 0010 1110 0101 0111.

Currently the value of bits from 7 to 11 (right to left) is 10011. I want to set it to 10110 for example. How do I do that?

Comment: Why unsigned long long? `std::vector<bool>` would work. Or I believe there is a standard library bit field.

Comment: `std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned long long) * CHAR_BIT>`

Comment: Boolean Arithmetic and uint64_t.  You will need to mask bits and shift them (either into position or shift them to the right for normal processing).

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking how to mask bits and extract them?  (The information is already on the internet.)

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the code for you, or did you have a specific issue you encountered along the way? What have you tried?

Comment: You could also consider [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)....

Comment: Remember, you are trading executable speed for data size here.  Extracting bits takes executable time.  Storing as uncompressed fields in a structure will improve your execution time, but waste more bits.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is common in the world of embedded systems.  Usually, manufacturers of hardware devices use bit fields to represent information, such as statuses.

### Inserting Into Your Number

This involves left shifting your number (such as birth year) into the appropriate position then ORing the value with your number:

```
unsigned int value;
//...
value |= (birth_year << 1);
```

### Extracting or Getting the Number:

You will need to AND the number with a *mask* so that only the important bits are extracted.  For example, retrieving gender:

```
unsigned int gender;
unsigned int value;
gender = value & 1;
// or 
gender = value & (~0);
```

You may need to right shift the bits to get the correct value, such as after extracting the birth year, right shift it by 1.

### Bit Field Structure

You can let the Compiler figure all this by using *bit fields* in a structure, something like:

```
struct Compressed_Number
{
  unsigned int  gender : 1;
  unsigned int  birth_year : 11;
  //..
};
```

I personally prefer the Boolean Arithmetic version because you always know the bit positions.

Comment: To be complete, you need to mask out the field that you're inserting, so something like:   `value = (value & ((~((1<<BIT_WIDTH)-1)<<LSB) ) | ((birth_year&((1<<BIT_WIDTH)-1) << LSB);`    It's a mess, but bitstuffing isn't ever pretty